# IIF expression - Overload Resolution Error

Tags: report, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I'm getting an error when executing the below IIF statement -

```
=IIF(
(First(Fields!ProcessDate.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct")=0)
OR
(First(Fields!ProcessDate.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct")=1)
,(Last(Fields!FXCCYUSD.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct"))
,(Fields!SecondtoLastUSDtoCCY.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct")
)
```

Error message:
"The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox115.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments."

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means there's a misplaced parenthesis somewhere or maybe it doesn't like the `OR` not being enclosed in parenthesis. Give this one a shot -- it should work as expected.

```
=IIF(((First(Fields!ProcessDate.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct")=0) OR
(First(Fields!ProcessDate.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct")=1))
,(Last(Fields!FXCCYUSD.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct"))
,(Fields!SecondtoLastUSDtoCCY.Value, "Currency_Date_GBP_Error_Acct"))
```

If it doesn't, double check your parenthesis, especially those around the `OR` portion of the expression.